# Error; "dropdownlist is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level" occurs on binding a dropdown.

Tags: asp.net

.aspx code 
`

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlLines" Height="164px" Width="286px">
<HeaderTemplate>
 <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="MyAccount" style="border-left: solid 1px silver; border-right: solid 1px silver;  border-bottom: solid 1px silver" width=555>
 <tr bgcolor="gray" style="COLOR: #ffffff" height=25>
    <td style="padding-left: 10px"><b>New Plan</b></td> 
 </tr>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 10px">                  
     <asp:dropdownlist ID="ddlRatePlan" runat="server"  AutoPostBack=true  style="width:150px;"></asp:dropdownlist> 
    </td>
 </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <FooterTemplate>
 </table>
 </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

`

VB code: 
`

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If IsPostBack Then Exit Sub
        BindRatePlans()
    End Sub

 Private Sub BindRatePlans()

        ddlRatePlan.DataSource = DB_GetTable("GetRateplans")
        ddlRatePlan.DataTextField = "RatePlanDesc"
        ddlRatePlan.DataValueField = "RatePlan"
        ddlRatePlan.DataBind()
 End Sub
```

`
With reference to the above snippet,
The table 'GetRateplans' has the columns 'RatePlanDesc' &'RatePlan'. The data from the column 'RatePlanDesc' should be bound to the dropdownlist on page load.

Note : I had verified that the call DB_GetTable("GetRateplans") returns some data.

Comment: Do you want to bind your 'dropdownlist' with values from the so called "RatePlanDesc" column on Page Load. 
Regarding the error try changing the access specifier of 'Private Sub BindRatePlans()' to public or protected.

Comment: yes i'm trying to bind the db results to the dropdown list control. how does it help the visibility of dropdownlist by changing the access modifier of the method

Comment: ddlRatePlan dropdown list is added in the webpage, and im trying to bind some data to this control on a pageload

Comment: Please click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) for clarifications on access modifiers.

Comment: changed the access modifier of the method, and it doesnt help.

Comment: Is that runtime error? Also please post your DB_GetTable method.

Comment: You can also play and try to test by setting your DataSource to empty List for example and see if error persists.

Comment: ddlRatePlan itself is not accessible. i tried to do this by giving some value instead of a dbdata.  IntelliSense is not coming for this ddlRatePlan.

Comment: its a compile time error, tried it with a c# code also and i still get the error